# Porting code from gcc to clang

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++11, clang

Hi I'm trying to make my code compile under clang 3.2-9, here is a simplified sample of what I can't get to compile :

```
template<template <class>class Derived, typename Type>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){}
};

template<typename Type>
class Bar
    : public Foo<Bar, Type>
{
    public:
        Bar()
            : Foo<Bar, Type>()
        {}
};

int main()
{
    Bar<int> toto;
}
```

And here is the error that clang tells me :

```
test.cpp:14:19: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template
            : Foo<Bar, Type>()
                  ^
test.cpp:14:15: error: expected class member or base class name
            : Foo<Bar, Type>()
              ^
test.cpp:14:15: error: expected '{' or ','
3 errors generated.
```

It compiles without any problem under gcc 4.7.2. And I can't get the right syntax to make it work under clang.
Can someone help me please, I'm kinda stuck ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified name for your class template:

```
template<template <class> class Derived, typename Type>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){}
};

template<typename Type>
class Bar
    : public Foo<::Bar, Type>
//               ^^^^^
{
    public:
        Bar()
            : Foo<::Bar, Type>()
//                ^^^^^
        {}
};

int main()
{
    Bar<int> toto;
}
```

The problem is that inside `Bar`, the name `Bar` refers to the class itself, i.e  to the *instantiation* of the `Bar` class template (i.e. `Bar<Type>`) rather than the template itself.

You can see this example compiling [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/122SnG$1).

Comment: Do you know if gcc should accept my version, or is it too permissive regarding the standard, or is clang right to trigger this error? (and if possible do you know which part of the standard talks about this issue?) Thanks

Comment: @b3nj1: What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: I use gcc 4.7.2. 
Oh and clang asks to have a space between <:: like this < ::

Comment: @b3nj1: GCC 4.7.2 expects a space as well, but not GCC 4.8.0 (beta) nor Clang 3.2

Comment: I think G++ is wrong to accept the original code. The relevant part of the standard is 9 [class]/2 which defines the _injected-class-name_. The space should not be required, but G++ 4.7 doesn't implement [lex.pptoken]/3